# RSA Encryption Javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, public-key

I have been instructed to write an application that takes some data then encrypts it with an RSA public key.

It needs to be "RSA encryption":

Which encryption cipher is RSA meant to use as standard?

```
var key = "TUlHZE1BMEdDU3FHU0liM0RRRUJBUVVBQTRHTEFEQ0Jod0tCZ1FDbVFiTWc3SWRpeHVmYWEwcDd2ODVLVytmUnVlZ216UUhibnNoWjhmbXlTQW9MMXRFVzAyNEZKVFlSTFZxN0VsV2p1R0U4aHQ3RmJjN1NURWpxZVViWU5xdnRiVWN6UFZYSE5FdStYRUVndGszazlFNXVQWG0wVzRIc3RtK0FhRXcyMmxxb2lFNGlrT1QzZzdPRXNHSVFCMVNlSlRtVTE1eFBBZ3M3SXRjTVFRSUJFUT09";

var data = "Xa21dr";
```

Comment: Your question doesn't explain what you've done to try and solve the problem; it currently reads like a request for code. Please share your attempted implementation and explain how it fails to meet your requirements.

Comment: First of all, there seems to be little reason to perform *double* base 64 encoding on a BER encoded PKCS#1 public key. (I was wondering why the data did not start with an uppercase `M` :)

Comment: @DuncanJones i am not asking for "code" if you read what i am asking you will understand my question i am asking HOW what is the fundamentals of encrypting a RSA public key and some data together because i cant find anything that works.

Comment: @owlstead yes that seems correct i have decoded the key before with base64 that will give you that for example - MIGdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GLADCBhwKBgQCmQbMg7Idixufaa0p7v85KW+fRuegmzQHbnshZ8fmySAoL1tEW024FJTYRLVq7ElWjuGE8ht7Fbc7STEjqeUbYNqvtbUczPVXHNEu+XEEgtk3k9E5uPXm0W4Hstm+AaEw22lqoiE4ikOT3g7OEsGIQB1SeJTmU15xPAgs7ItcMQQIBEQ== but apparently the key must stay intact how its received then encrypt the data with it bytes[] to be sent out.

Comment: you obvious don't know how RSA works then, nevermind this has all been sorted now!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found the answer -

RSA Encryption standard uses PKCS #1

Best library to use is pidCrypt, nothing else worked for me!

**pidCrypt**
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pidcrypt/

**Forge**
https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

They failed to let me know that the RSA Public Key was meant to be base64 decoded also before encrypting the DATA before posting.

Comment: What is the format of the encrypted data? Is it also base 64?

Comment: pidder is no longer online?

Comment: @Toubey looks to be still online to me just checked their website - https://www.pidder.com/pidcrypt/ - still accessible. you can download from source forge directly too - http://sourceforge.net/projects/pidcrypt/

Comment: The project is no longer maintained. Also @whitedeath - can you clarify whether it implemented PKCS#1 v1.5 (which is understand is easily attackable since 1998) or PKCS#1 v2.2 (RSA with Optimal Asymmetric Encryption Padding). For those reasons and ease of use i went with forge, which also is a pretty active project on github.

Comment: @Philzen No idea which PKCS v is packaged with pidCrypt you will need to download the source and take a look (i needed PKCS #1 so went with pidCrypt as it worked perfectly for my needs).

Comment: Note: pidCrypt is licensed under GPL (thus, your software must legally also be licensed under GPL if you use the library)

Answer (score 13):

You may be interested in trying out forge (it does RSA and more). There are lots of examples on the README:

https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

Comment: thanks, pidCrypt is working perfectly but will take a look. pidCrypt offers not just RSA too.

Comment: forge is very nice. I had a little trouble getting it started, so I created the demo here: http://digitalbazaar.github.io/forge/