# RSACryptoServiceProvider encryption using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, rsa

I have a below cSharp code that does encryption with a public key.  I was asked to do the same with Javascript/NodeJS.  Is this even possible to do it?  This is the first time I doing any kind of encryption.   Please help me understanding what are the difficulties I may face if I proceed for this.  Are there any plugins to do this?

```
public static string EncryptAsymmetric(string encryptText, string publicKey)
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        bool fOAEP = false;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptText);
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            provider.FromXmlString(publicKey);
            buffer = provider.Encrypt(bytes, fOAEP);
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RSA Encryption Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685645/rsa-encryption-javascript)

Comment: If you are looking a RSA implementation in javascript, this questio is not related to c#.